# MVC null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am making my MVC application. One view includes a form. After filling it, the form is validated and if model is valid, then it should move to another window, but if not, nothing should happen, but apparently, some of the data is lost then. My controller:

```
  public ActionResult PickGroupForHomework(PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel model)
        {
            ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2();
            model.groups = entities.Groups.ToList();
            model.users = entities.Users.ToList();
            int id = model.subject_id;
            var subj = entities.Subjects
                    .Where(b => b.class_id == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            model.subject_name = subj.name;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                if (subj != null)
                {
                    model.subject_name = subj.name;
                }
                model.subject_id = model.subject_id;
                model.groups = entities.Groups.ToList();
                model.users = entities.Users.ToList();
                return View(model);
            }
            return View(model);

        }
```

And apparently `subject_id` and `qty` is null after false validation. Why?

Comment: Run it in the debugger to be sure, but my guess is its the _first_ time you do `model.subject_name = subj.name;` since `subj` could be null.  That said, there are a few ways to clean up the code to make it clearer (e.g. `model.subject_id = model.subject_id`?)

Comment: If you are changing data in the controller that comes in as an argument to the action then you need ModelState.Clear()    This is a binding issue.

Comment: cant understand what you mean by And apparently subject_id and qty is null after false validation.

Comment: @Steve view loads. Someone puts wrong input and ModelState is not valid, the window is reloaded and then the data loss occurs

Comment: @MaciejMiśkiewicz define data loss. you need to make the flow and the result more clear to get an accurate answer

Comment: Have you bind the subject_id in the view ... may be using such as HiddenFor(x=>x.subject_id) something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have in the view, a field or hidden field binding to the Subject_Id property from your model? If you don't have at least a hidden field that binds to a property from a model in a strongly typed view, this data will be lost when your user posts the form and your controller is called.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Subject_Id)
```